# How to ensure application availability when one or more microservices fail?

Tags: microservices

If a microservice is not responding due to any of the following reasons, how do we ensure the overall application availability?

1. Microservice crashes
2. Network partition happens or other transient error happens
3. Service is overloaded

Comment: Hi Anuj, please could you add some more details of the environment that you are building in. Also, please could you let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: have you tired to do something

Comment: Please, add some more details

Answer (score 0):

> other microservice calling the same microservice

If you have services calling one another, that doesn't sound like they are using Kafka, then.

If you have applications sending to Kafka, then those messages are persisted to the broker logs. Any downstream consumer can stay offline for as long as the messages are (configurably) retained in the Kafka cluster.

Ultimately, when using Kafka (any persistent message queue), services do not know about one another, and only the brokers.

Comment: Okay .. If interservice commincation is happening with REST API and 1 microservice is down , then how will we resolve this issue ?@cricket_007

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your post was about Kafka, not RESTful services (or gRPC, for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid coupling in microservices architecture as much as possible.

In your case, I guess you are sending a read-only request to a microservice to get a data but called microservice is not up. So caller microservice can't do its job.

To avoid this kind of situations you can use data duplication technique. In this technique microservice which is the source of the data send insert, update, delete information about the data as an event with using a broker like Kafka. Then other microservices which also needs to this data get the data from corresponding topic. By this way, you don't need to make a read-only request to get the data. Then you will avoid coupling between microservices.

> What will happen in that case?

In this case, if there is no redundancy for microservice which is called, caller microservice will get an exception like "No instances available for CalledMicroservice"